# nested docker setup: child exposes parent

Tags: docker, jenkins

I' have the following docker setup:

```
Ubuntu server
  -> running Jenkins (started with docker-compose)
       -> running a pipeline which starts a node-alpine image
            -> which then calls a new docker-compose up (needed for tests)
```

If I call `docker ps` from the node-alpine container, I see all the containers from the ubuntu server. I would have expected to only see the newly started containers.

Is this an indication that my setup is flawed? Or just the way docker works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the way Docker works.  There's no such thing as a hierarchy of containers.

Typically with setups like this you give an orchestrator (like Jenkins) access to the host's Docker socket.  That means containers launched from Jenkins are indistinguishable from containers launched directly from the host, and it means that Jenkins can do anything with Docker that you could have done from the host.

Remember that access to the Docker socket means reading and modifying arbitrary files as root on the host, along with starting, stopping, deleting, and replacing other containers.  In this setup you might re-evaluate how much you really need that lowest level container to start further containers, since it is a significant security exposure.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!